# My smoke simulation always scales up with the domain?

Tags: baking, smoke-simulation

[image]
[image]
[image]
I've been trying to create this simple explosion for about two days now with no luck. The smoke always hits the edges of the domain within a few frames of starting. I've tried countless troubleshooting steps to fix this but nothing works. I've completely run out of ideas. The photos show the domain at three different sizes with no success.

Things I've tried:

Applying scale after changing domain

Turning off adaptive domain

Recreated scene multiple times

Found explosion tutorials and followed steps exactly (I ended up with very different results than the tuts)

Tried on three different Blender versions (2.82, 2.83, 2.83.1)

Reset Blender to factory settings

Tried different smoke resolutions

Tried on another computer

Ive got nothing else to try... any ideas?
The Blend file: [Blend File](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/drVNQ5A9)

Comment: Upload your blend file here instead: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and [edit] the question with the new link. Pastebin links are temporary.

Comment: Did you try freeing the data and baking again? Also, are you scaling the domain after creating the smoke simulation?

Comment: I've updated the question with the new link.

Comment: Yes, I did free and bake the data quite a few times. I've tried scaling the domain both before and after creating the simulation. I get the same results either way.